# How can I resize the Applications menu item in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux, and in the top left corner of my screen there's an Applications menu, with items like this:

```
01 - Info...
02 - Vul...
03 - We...
```

How can I enlarge the menu, so that the entire folder names would fit?

I've found the file containing all the menu items (`/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/kali-applications.menu`), but there seems to be no way to edit the width, or preferably make it auto-fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue in Kali Linux and found the solution here:

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?33063-Application-Menu-Width-Issues

The author expressed his suspicion that there must be a better solution but it worked for me like a charm. No more guessing what the menu item does!

The essence of the answer is here:

Edit this file (may require root privilege):

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js
```

Look for...

```
this.categoriesBox.box.width = 300;
```

(just search for 300)

...and replace it with:

```
this.mainBox.box.width = 950;
this.categoriesBox.box.width = 500;
```

Save, logout, and log back in. Should be much better.

If not, play around with those numbers. Main box is the width of the entire menu; categories box is obviously the size of the categories box within the main box.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me. I also asked this question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1243547/how-can-i-resize-the-applications-menu-item-in-gnome) and offered a bounty there. If you want, you can answer there as well to earn 50 reputation.